# Trying to write to a MS Access file on Python 3.10 using pyodbc

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to write to a MS Access file using pyodbc, but I keep on getting an error message.

This is my code:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
                      r"DBQ=<File address>;")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from Products")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)


item = input("Enter the name of the item: ")
price = input("Enter the price of the item: ")

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Products (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Price)"
               "VALUES ("6", "item", Decimal("price"))")
cursor.commit()
```

But when I try to run the code, it doesn't even run the code before outputting an error message "invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?" while highlighting the first quotation mark on

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Products (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Price)"
               "VALUES ("6", "item", Decimal("price"))")
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: use query parameters as described [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters)

Comment: Should there be an ampersand and a space in there somewhere as in       --- Product_Price)" & " VALUES

Comment: Look again at your highlighted code in the question. Why is `6` highlighted as number and `item` - as variable? Hint: what encloses the string? How should python understand whether the quote is a part of the string?

Comment: @user10186832 - That would be required in VBA code, but not in Python. In Python `('Hello' 'World')` produces `'HelloWorld'`

Comment: @gord should there be a space in there to correct the resulting SQL as in Product_Price)""VALUES resulting in Product_Price)VALUES rather than Product_Price) VALUES

Comment: @user10186832 - SQL parsers can be pretty forgiving, and in this case Access SQL does not complain about `Product_Price)VALUES`

Comment: I expect Product_ID is a number field. Don't use quote marks or apostrophes to delimit parameter. Also, replace the embedded quote marks with apostrophes. Is Product_ID an autonumber field?

Comment: Don't you need \ character for line continuation?